# Lazy load Issue : Hibernate 3, Spring 4, Jackson 2.4.0

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

My Project is using

- Spring 4.0.5.RELEASE
- Hibernate 3.6.0.FINAL
- jackson-datatype-hibernate3-2.4.0.jar

**ISSUE:** /Spring4HibernateMaven/contacts/3 produces LazyInitializationException!!

Changing ObjectMapper (pls see spring-servlet.xml) to com.company.gis.ucvs.ioe.json.HibernateAwareObjectMapper to convert Contact POJO to JSON Fails with an exception. However, if I just create a dummy Contact object, POJO to JSON conversion works fine. What is it I am missing? Really appreciate your help/pointers..Thanks!

**STACK TRACE**

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
    org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
    org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
    com.company.gis.ucvs.ioe.form.Contact_$$_javassist_6.getId(Contact_$$_javassist_6.java)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.get(BeanPropertyWriter.java:726)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:506)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:114)
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1837)
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:253)

**SNIPPETS FROM spring-servlet.xml**

```
<!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
<bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
**<!--  bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" /-->
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.company.gis.ucvs.ioe.json.HibernateAwareObjectMapper" />**

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
<property name="targetObject" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
<property name="targetMethod" value="configure" />
<property name="arguments">
    <list>
        <value type="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature">FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES</value>
        <value>false</value>
    </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

**SNIPPETS from ContactController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contacts/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody Contact getContact(@PathVariable Integer id)  {

    //Contact c = new Contact(); <--- Sample contact POJO to JSON works fine
    //c.setEmail("NO EMAIL");
    Contact c = contactService.getContact(id);
    return c;

}
```

**SNIPPETS from ContactServiceImpl.java**

```
@Transactional
public Contact getContact(Integer id) {
    Contact c = contactDAO.getContact(id);
    return c;

}
```

**SNIPPET from ContactDaoImpl.java**

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public Contact getContact(Integer id) {
    Contact contact = (Contact) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(
            Contact.class, id);
    return contact;
}
```

**SNIPPETS from HibernateAwareObjectMapper**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class HibernateAwareObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public HibernateAwareObjectMapper() {
        Hibernate3Module hm = new Hibernate3Module();
        registerModule(hm);  
        //Whether lazy-loaded object should be forced to be loaded and then serialized (true); or serialized as nulls (false).Default value is false. 
        hm.configure(Hibernate3Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING, true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Describe the exact problem you want to solve and what have you tried so far to solve it. Read carefully the http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: This problem deals with your @Transactional. Jackson is trying to load your Contact object which is having one to many mapping with some other object and your fetch type is Lazy. You should have search on net for this problem. SO says you post the question only when you don't get answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with detached entities. As soon as your objects leave `@Transactional` methods, they are detached. Either convert those to DTO's (data transfer objects) or unproxy your objects, see http://java-success.blogspot.de/2012/09/understanding-hibernate-proxy-objects.html